# deferred iteration of IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, generic-collections

Trying to build a asp.net mvc html helper for creating a bootstrap table. I've defined my fluent interface as follows:

```
public interface IBootstrapObject: IHtmlString
{
    IBootstrapObject Name(string name);
    IBootstrapObject AddClass(params string[] classNames);
    //IBootstrapObject RemoveClass(params string[] classNames);
}
```

So the implementing class now has to have a `ToHtmlString()` definition. The underlying data  that this table helper would bind to could be something like a `List<Person>` (assume `Person` it has standard properties here like `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc).

Hence say I've defined the following:

```
public class BootstrapTable : IBootstrapObject
{
    IEnumerable _dataSet;
    public IBootstrapObject DataSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataSet)
    {
        _modelType = typeof(T);
        _dataset = dataSet;
        return this;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {

    }

    //remaining code ...
}
```

How to access the `IEnumerable<T>` passed during in the `DataSet<T>()` inside of `ToHtmlString()` ?

In one sense, I know this involves caching it somewhere, and re-accessing it inside ToHtmlString(). And that is why I used `_dataSet`. How to convert that `IEnumerable` to the generic `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Any problems with casting?

Comment: Well, `Cast<_modelType>()` throws a compile error?

Comment: I mean `((IEnumerable<T>)_dataSet)`. And why not just make `_dataSet` `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Why do you *need* it as an `IEnumerable<T>`? Of course, you could make `BootstrapTable` generic... It's not clear what you want the code wihthin `ToHtmlString` to *do* with the `IEnumerable<T>` once you've got it, which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: @Athari: There's no `T` here - `DataSet<T>` is a generic *method*...

Comment: @JonSkeet the goal is to reflect the properties of `T` - that would form the table's header row.

Comment: @deostroll: Well you can do that without having an `IEnumerable<T>`. Just iterate over the non-generic `IEnumerable` - if you're accessing the data with reflection, it doesn't matter whether you're asking for properties from an `object` or a `T`. I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I do want a specific order to it? My apologies, for my design as of now is really not complete. I realize specific hurdles along the way. I want the design of this helper to be similar to [kendo's grid implementation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html). We have the option of re-ordering columns, giving it custom names, etc...

Comment: If you want to add extra orderings, there are lots of different ways of doing it... but I'm not going to keep on adding bits to the answer as you discover more requirements along the way, I'm afraid. You really need to think of one *very specific* question at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to access it as an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can just use the non-generic `IEnumerable`:

```
var properties = _modelType.GetProperties(); // Or whatever... remove indexers etc
foreach (object item in _dataSet)
{
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(item, null);
        // Use the value somehow
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to have it as an `IEnumerable<T>`, and you don't want the type itself to be generic, then you'll need a generic method, which you can then call by reflection or using dynamic typing to do the heavy lifting:

```
public string ToHtmlString()
{
    dynamic data = _dataSet;
    ToHtmlString(data);
}

private string ToHtmlString<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that using dynamic typing like this, `T` may not be the same `T` as in the original method. An alternative using reflection:

```
public string ToHtmlString()
{
    var method = typeof(BootstrapTable).GetMethod("ToHtmlStringImpl",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var concreteMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(_modelType);
    concreteMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { _dataSet });
}

private string ToHtmlStringImpl<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    ...
}
```